# OpenServer долгие http запросы

Tags: openserver

Развернул локально проект на Laravel и поставил его на OpenServer. Проблема заключается в том что иногда обычный GET запрос выполняется очень долго и в логах сервера его даже нет. Кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой, подскажите как решить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась видимо в гугл хроме. Не знаю что за фигня, но я даже запросов не видел, просто крутящийся лоадер и все. Установил Firefox и все заработало нормально. Первый раз такое вижу

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите внешнюю подкачку чего-то в проекте, либо перебои с инетом вообще - замечено, что если сеть есть , а инета нет, то тормозят локалки сильно.

Решение - по возможности - вообще отключить инет/сеть - тогда просто летает. Попробуйте.

Часто в проектах есть второстепенные внешние моменты - CDN, счетчики, например, встраиваемые через iframe элементы, картинки, автопарсирование внешних ресурсов (даже с проверкой доступности - все одно время) и прочее - при проблемах с инетом картина именно такая. Или при проблемах с доступностью некоторых внешних элементов/ресурсов.

Comment: Очень странная ситуация. Жму на линк по переходу на опреденную страничку и все затухает, ни ответа ни запроса в логах. Копирую линк и вставляю в браузер в том же виде, грузится нормально. Сеть отключил так же история

Comment: Если линк отрабатывает нормально (а он запущен под OpenServer), то вопрос, вероятно, все-таки в ларавеле - возможно, конфигурация, контролер либо еще что. Бывает еще, при частом переключении на open и обратно - даже ctrl f5 не спасает - нужно либо перманетное отключение кэша или чистка. Может еще быть, конфликт с портами и перенаправлениями неявный - то есть, порт занимается, в hosts все должно прописываться - но провис есть. Такое наблюдалось, когда давно надо было обновить виндовс, да все отлаживалось, в результате все начало чудить - до перезапуска и установки обявлений.

Comment: Посмотрите еще hosts - иногда некорректна чистка/запись. Попробуйте поставить laravel на тестовый поддомен в инете и посмотрите - возможно, проблема в нем, или потребуется переустановить начисто Open - собственно, у меня два варианта стоит Open - совсем новый и периодически аккуратно обновляемый своим методом - так вот, иногда некоторые конфигурации на одном запускаются, на другом нет. В общем - надо бы разделить и локализовать возможную проблему. Я все-таки думаю на laravel.